# Join two lines into one line using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

iam trying to creat csv file from .txt file and now iam stuck at this point

**Sample text file**

```
http://website1.com/imageartist.png,Artis Name,Pop Rock
https://website2/music/mymusicpop.mp3

https://website43.com/albumimages.png,Artis Name,K-Pop
http://website7/music/mymusickpop.mp3

https://website23.com/anotherimage.png,Artis Name,Heavy Metal
www.website5/music/mymusicmetal.mp3

www.website63.com/singerimage.png,Artis Name,Jazz
https.website5/music/mymusicjazz <-some lines have no .mp3 extension
```

**i want like this**

```
http://website1.com/imageartist.png,Artis Name,Pop Rock,https://website2/music/mymusicpop.mp3

https://website43.com/albumimages.png,Artis Name,K-Pop,http://website7/music/mymusickpop.mp3

https://website23.com/anotherimage.png,Artis Name,Heavy Metal,www.website5/music/mymusicmetal.mp3

www.website63.com/singerimage.png,Artis Name,Jazz,https.website5/music/mymusicjazz
```

how can i do this using notepad++?

Comment: I dont understand what your problem is? Take the text you want it to look like and save it as something.csv. That's it ?

Comment: @Philipp 
the real problem is not creating a csv file, but combining 2 lines into 1 line ... but I don't know how to combine them with a pattern like that ... I can't do Ctrl + j, because there are thousands of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will join lines separated by a single linebreak.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\K\R(?!\R)`
- Replace with: `,`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  .+                # 1 or more any character but newline
  \K                # forget all we have seen until this position
  \R                # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  (?!\R)            # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a linebreak after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression on Notepad++, and a backreference

```
(([^\r\n]+))(\r\n)?(([^\r\n]+))(\r\n)?
```

**UPDATED**: this ignores newline break types

```
(([^\r\n]+))([\r\n])?(([^\r\n]+))([\r\n])?
```

[image]

[image]

\1 -- first line URL

\4 -- second line URL

\3 -- the new line is taken from group 3

FYI: don't run it more than once (Replace All). It will keep replacing

Comment: Have you really tried it? For me it is just inserting a comma before the last character in each line. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4OHfqS/1)

Comment: If you said, I trust you, but I don't get the desired result with Npp 7.8.1

Comment: Sorry, I've tested with EOL `\n`, it works with `\r\n`.

Comment: @Toto you are right...  a much better solution would have been `(([^\r\n]+))([\r\n])?(([^\r\n]+))([\r\n])?` . No matter the new line break